# Alert dialog closes without pressing the button

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building an android app with a signup activity. When the signup is successful, I want to show an alertbox with a success message and go back to the parent activity.
The problem is that the alertbox is shown only for a brief time and then I go back immediately to the parent activity, without pressing any button in the alertbox.
my code is:

```
case RESPONSE_USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS:              
            showAlertBoxSignupSuccess();
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            returnIntent.putExtra("email", email);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);        
            this.finish();
            break;

private void showAlertBoxSignupSuccess() 
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertbox.setTitle("The account was successfuly created");
    alertbox.setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
        {
            arg0.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertbox.show();


}
```

My question is, how can I make it wait until the the user clicks the button in the alertbox and then go to the parent activity?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to wait until the user presses the OK button to leave the current activity, you should move the code beneath  `showAlertBoxSignupSuccess();` into your button's `onClick` listener:

```
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) 
    {
        arg0.dismiss();
        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("email", email);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);        
        this.finish();
    }
```

Comment: @Sharon Haim Pour if a user has answered your question and resolved your issue, you should accept their answer by clicking on the tick just below the voting scores.  Accepting answers makes other users more likely to help you in the future.